# Find non-intersecting parts of a strings vector

Tags: r, string, intersect

I have a `string` `vector`.

For example:

```
vec <- c("aa.30.1","aa.40.1","aa.50.1")
```

But it may also be:

```
vec2 <- c("a2bsx","a2bsy","a2bsz")
```

Or even:

```
vec3 <- c("mean.ln.scaled.ST_mus.control.30.1","mean.ln.scaled.ST_mus.control.60.1","mean.ln.scaled.ST_mus.control.150.1","mean.ln.scaled.ST_mus.control.300.1","mean.ln.scaled.STN_mus.control.1440.1")
```

And I'm looking for a function that will return the non-overlapping right tails of the vector's elements.

For `vec` the result would be:

```
c("30.1","40.1","50.1")
```

For `vec2`:

```
vec2 <- c("x","y","z")
```

And For `vec3`:

```
vec3 <- c("30.1","60.1","150.1","300.1","1440.1")
```

Any function that can capture all cases?

Comment: I see `0.1` repeated three times. Do you not want that to be considered repeated?

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Brēza. I updated my post.

Comment: `stringr::str_extract(string = vec, pattern = "\\d+")`

Comment: @d.b Your answer reminds me why I need to get better at regex. Also this reason: https://xkcd.com/208/

Comment: @AndrewBrēza, regex is like magic to me. If I knew it, I wouldn't be using `stringr`. And there is really a xkcd for everything!

Comment: @dan in the first case, your criteria would actually return `c("3", "4", "5")`, otherwise, you will have to use some delimiter to split the individual strings (like "." in the first example) .

Comment: agreed - just corrected it

Comment: Are the left parts of the strings that need to be removed always the same length as in vec and vec2? Also, if it's not a typo in vec3, shouldn't the result be: `c("T_mus.control.150.1","T_mus.control.300.1","N_mus.control.1440.1")`?

Comment: Hi @dan you received a lot of great responses. Please consider accepting one (by clicking on the check mark to the left) that was most helpful to you. This lets the community know that that answer worked in your case as well.

Answer (score 2):

#### Data

Woops! Forgot to mention that you had a typo in the last element of `vec3`.

```
vec3 <- c("mean.ln.scaled.ST_mus.control.30.1","mean.ln.scaled.ST_mus.control.60.1","mean.ln.scaled.ST_mus.control.150.1","mean.ln.scaled.ST_mus.control.300.1","mean.ln.scaled.ST_mus.control.1440.1")
```

Use this recursive function, which compares the first character of every entry in the vector (`temp[[x]][1]`), and checks if they are the same or not (`length(unique(sapply(1:length(temp), function(x) temp[[x]][1])))>1`). If they are not the same, return the remaining characters (to the right) as a string (`sapply(1:length(temp), function(x) paste0(temp[[x]], collapse=""))`), else, call the function again to check the next character.

```
special <- function(v) {
            temp <- strsplit(v, "")
            y <- sapply(1:length(temp), function(x) length(temp[[x]]))
            mincol <- min(y)
            maxcol <- max(y)
            is.unique <- length(unique(sapply(1:length(temp), function(x) temp[[x]][1])))>1
            if (is.unique == TRUE) {
                  ans <- sapply(1:length(temp), function(x) paste0(temp[[x]], collapse=""))
                  return(ans)
            } else {
                  tryagain <- sapply(1:length(temp), function(x) paste0(temp[[x]][2:y[x]], collapse=""))
                  special(tryagain)
            }
       }

special(vec)
#"30.1" "40.1" "50.1"

special(vec2)
#"x" "y" "z"

special(vec3)
#"30.1"   "60.1"   "150.1"  "300.1"  "1440.1"
```

#### Watch for error

```
What if all the entries are the same?

test <- c("abc","abc","abc")

special(test)
#Error: node stack overflow
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
gsub("\\D+", "", gsub(paste(Reduce(intersect, strsplit(vec, "[.]")), collapse="|"), "", vec))
#[1] "30" "40" "50"
```

Comment: Well this code is not working for `vec2` or even `vec3`. It must have just been written for `vec` in mind. can you please provide a general code? Tha can solve all of the above?

Comment: its okay. Thank you.. its great

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this will help:

```
 funfun=function(x){
    for(i in 1:(nchar(x[1])+1)){
      y=substr(x[1],1,i)
      w=which(grepl(y,x)==FALSE)
      if(length(w)>0)break
    }
  gsub(substr(x[1],1,i-1),"",x)
 }


vec1 <- c("aa.30.1","aa.40.1","aa.50.1")
vec2 <- c("a2bsx","a2bsy","a2bsz")
funfun(vec1)
[1] "30.1" "40.1" "50.1"
funfun(vec2)
[1] "x" "y" "z"
```

I realized `vec3` as given above has a STN in the last element which is different from the rest:

```
  vec3
 [1] "mean.ln.scaled.ST_mus.control.30.1"      "mean.ln.scaled.ST_mus.control.60.1"     
 [3] "mean.ln.scaled.ST_mus.control.150.1"     "mean.ln.scaled.ST_mus.control.300.1"    
 [5] "mean.ln.scaled.STN_mouse.control.1440.1"

 funfun(vec3)
[1] "_mus.control.30.1"      "_mus.control.60.1"      "_mus.control.150.1"    
[4] "_mus.control.300.1"     "N_mouse.control.1440.1".
```

If we use the first four elements of vec3:

```
 funfun(vec3[-5])
[1] "30.1"  "60.1"  "150.1" "300.1"
```

or if we change the last element of vec3 by removing the **N** after **ST** and changing from mouse to mus as the rest

```
  vec3[5]
 [1] "mean.ln.scaled.STN_mouse.control.1440.1"
  vec3[5]="mean.ln.scaled.ST_mus.control.1440.1"
 funfun(vec3)
 [1] "30.1"   "60.1"   "150.1"  "300.1"  "1440.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
library(stringr)
difftail = function(x) gsub(tail(Reduce(intersect,lapply(x,function(x) str_sub(x,1,1:nchar(x)))),1),"",x)

difftail(vec)
[1] "30.1" "40.1" "50.1"

difftail(vec2)
[1] "x" "y" "z"

difftail(vec3)
[1] "_mus.control.30.1"    "_mus.control.60.1"    "_mus.control.150.1"   "_mus.control.300.1"   "N_mus.control.1440.1"
```